# Opposite of tabbing down the page?

Tags: tabs, navigation

When viewing a webpage, tab can be used to cycle through the page's links and inputs fields from the top down.  What I would like to know is if there is a way to do this backwards, say if you hit tab one too many times and wanted to go back.  Is there a keyboard shortcut for this I am unaware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

usually SHIFT-tab is the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

```
Shift+Tab
```

Should do what you are looking for